# Не записывается в бд

Tags: c#, sql-server

Уже третий день мучаюсь, не могу занести данные в БД. MSSQL Server 2016. Вообще логика такая: пользователь вводит боту логин/пароль, он авторизуется на сайте и параллельно записываем человека в БД. Если в базе есть такой пользователь, то ничего не делаем

```
static class DatabaseInstance
{
    static private readonly string connectionString = "Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename = C:\\Users\\Blackbirder\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\\Instances\\MSSQLLocalDB\\University.mdf; Integrated Security = True";

    static public void DbInsert(string login, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (var _find = new SqlCommand("SELECT Login FROM Students", connection))
                {
                 //   connection.Open();
                    SqlDataReader _reader = _find.ExecuteReader();

                    while (_reader.Read())
                    {

                        if (_reader.ToString() == login)
                        {
                            connection.Close();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    _reader.Close();
                }

                using (var _insertDb = new SqlCommand($"INSERT INTO [Students] ([Login], [Password]) VALUES ({login}, {password})", connection))
                {
                    _insertDb.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

пишет Invalid column name 'somepassword'
Получаю login и password таким образом:

```
if (e.Message.Text == "/start")
                Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, @"Введите логин и пароль через пробел");

            user_data = e.Message.Text.Split(' ');
        //    Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, web.Authorize(user_data[0], user_data[1]));

            if (web.Authorize(user_data[0], user_data[1]).Contains("Вы вошли"))
            {
                Task task = new Task(() => DatabaseInstance.DbInsert(user_data[0], user_data[1]));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оставим за скобками **хранение паролей в открытом виде**.

Проблема вставки в том, что Вы пытаетесь вставить строку, но не берете значение в кавычки. Простое решение, но неправильное:

```
_insertDb = new SqlCommand($"INSERT INTO [Students] ([Login], [Password]) VALUES ('{login}', '{password}')", connection))
```

Неправильное из-за уязвимости для [внедрения SQL-кода](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0).
Старайтесь использовать в запросах параметризацию:

```
using (var _insertDb = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Students] ([Login], [Password]) VALUES (@login, @password)", connection))
{
    _insertDb.Parameters.Add("@login", SqlDbType.VarChar, 32).Value = login;
    _insertDb.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 32).Value = password;
    _insertDb.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Здесь `SqlDbType.VarChar` и `32` должны соответствовать типу и размеру колонок таблицы Students.